# Violation of PRIMARY KEY in entity with existing values in collection property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this entities:

```
public class Partner
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PersonId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }    
    public string Username { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<Partner> Partners { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Project
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    public ICollection<Partner> Partners { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

When I insert a new project, I have in the `Partners` property (`Project` class) existing partners, or in `Person` property (`Partner` class) existing persons. When this happens, the exception "Violation of PRIMARY KEY" occurs.

My code to sabe `Projects` is this:

```
//GetAllProject return IList<ProjectModel>
var projects = this.findProjectService.GetAllProjects(); 

foreach(var project in projects)
{
    var projectDb = context.Project.Where(e => e.Id == project.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (projectDb == null)
    {
        logger.Debug("Try add new project {0}", project.Name);
        var newProject = Mapper.Map<ProjectModel, Project>(project);
        context.Project.Add(newProject);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

How I can prevent this problem?

**Edit for include mapping:**

```
    internal PartnerMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        this.Ignore(t => t.Name);

        this.Property(t => t.PersonId)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        // Table
        this.ToTable("Partner");

        // Relations
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Project)
            .WithMany(r => r.Partners)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProjectId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Person)
            .WithMany(r => r.Partners)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.PersonId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

    internal PersonMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        this.Ignore(t => t.Username);

        // Table
        this.ToTable("Person");

        // Relations
    }

    internal ProjectMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        this.Property(t => t.Client)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        // Table
        this.ToTable("Project");

        // Relations
    }
```

Comment: can you show the mapping setup of the automapper and the ef data annotations for the keys?

Comment: Did you check `PersonId` and `ProjectId` in newProject.Partners before SaveChanges? Those should be either defaults (null, 0) or the same as in database.

Comment: @SherifAhmed yes, I include mapping

Comment: @nrodic no, I'm not check that, because the project is new, but sometimes the person or the partner exisit in the database.

Comment: It seems to me that `Partner`-`Project` should be many to many. Presently, partners you associate with a project can only belong to *that* project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of the `mapping` because all of your entities in the project `Partners` & `Persons` are detached from the context ... please check below the right approach to use the mapping ... (this is only a hint not the full solution)

you should also check the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` for your entities keys to make them `Identity` or you have to submit them with each insert.

```
//GetAllProject return IList<ProjectModel>
var projects = this.findProjectService.GetAllProjects(); 

foreach(var project in projects)
{
    var projectDb = context.Project.Where(e => e.Id == project.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (projectDb == null)
    {
        // the next line will map you a newproject and all of the partners and persons inside the each parnter if found ...
        // so you will get some entities which should be attached to the context in order for the ef to regonise that you mean not to insert new, but just to map them to the new project .. so
        //var newProject = Mapper.Map<ProjectModel, Project>(project);

        var newProject = context.Project.Create();
        // you should setup your mapping to not map the ID and let each mapsetup to map an entity itself not it's child entities
        newProject = Mapper.Map<ProjectModel, Project>(project);

        // loop all partners in the PROJECT MODEL
        foreach(var partner in project.PartnerModels) 
            ToPartners(partner, newProject.Partners);

        context.Project.Add(newProject);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public void ToPartners(PartnerModel model, ICollection<Partner> partners)
{
    var partnerDb = context.Partner.Where(e => e.Id == model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    if(parterDb == null) 
    {
        var newPartner = context.Partner.Create();
        newPartner = Mapper.Map<PartnerModel, Partner>(model);

        // loop all persons in the PARTNER MODEL
        foreach(var person in model.PersonsModel) 
            ToPersons(person, newPartner.Persons);

        partners.Add(newPartner);
    }
    else
    {
        // loop all persons in the PARTNER MODEL
        foreach(var person in model.PersonsModel) 
            ToPersons(person, partnerDb.Persons);

        // here the partner is attached to the context so he will not insert a new one, it will just add (map) it to the project.
        partners.Add(parterDb);
    }
}

public void ToPersons(PersonModel model, ICollection<Person> persons)
{
    // MAP IT 
}
```